# CSS Trying to understand Alternate syntax when creating drop down list in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, syntax, cascadingdropdown

I am seeing two different ways of referring to the unordered lists (`<ul>`), list items (`<li>`) and anchors (`<a>`).

I want to set the attributes of these items in a drop down list with at least two levels of nested `<ul>`.

My question is specifically about the ways to refer to the different levels of `<ul>`, `<li>` and `<a>` there in.

I have named the navigation bar `id="navBar"`.

I have seen on youtube: [Building a drop down navigation bar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7ayE5AtRUA)

The syntax used is:

```
ul#navBar .sub1 li
ul#navBar .sub1 li a
```

Where the class "*.sub1*" has been defined, and is the first level of *nested* `<ul>`, and "*.sub2*" is the second level of nested `<ul>`.

Referencing these levels, the code used is.

```
ul#navBar .sub2 a {
                  background-color: blue;}

ul#navBar li:hover > a {
            background-color: #CFC;
            }
```

It seems to me, that going to the bother of defining *.sub1* and *.sub2* is superfluous, and I have been using the format:

```
#navBar ul li{ background-color: blue;}

#navBar ul li:hover ul{ background-color: red;}
```

REAL QUESTION:

What is the correct syntax, using my (code just above) style of formatting. To refer to a second level nested `<ul>` and affect the `<li>` or the `<a>` there in?

I assumed it was along the lines of:

```
 #navBar ul li ul li: hover ul{ background-color: red;}
```

But I am wrong :(

Comment: Edit was fine, but I don't think I have the rep to approve, or even if that approval was needed. But I reviewed it and it looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that there should never be a space before `:hover`.

So the basic HTML structure you're outlining is:

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li>
        <ul class="sub1">
            <li>
                <ul class="sub2">
                    <li><a>Text</a><li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To refer to the `li` and `a` within `.sub2`, you'd write:

```
#navbar ul ul li { style to apply to li }
#navbar ul ul li a { style to apply to a }
#navbar ul ul li:hover { style to apply to li on hover }
#navbar ul ul li:hover a { style to apply to a on li hover }
```

The reason the tutorial assigned classes is because using generic nested element is a really inefficient way of using CSS selectors; it's faster to use classes. For more info, see [this article from CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/).

Comment: Dear Fluoxetine:
Fantastic article, the line I like best is:

"In other words, a selector like this is an efficiency disaster:"
referring to: (html) 'body ul li a {  } '

Your answer is also spot on, I think I am somewhat autistic, if I see two ways of doing something, I know there is reason behind the action.

I then also know I have a known unknown, to quote Donald and his famous unknown unknowns speech.

I will read all three articles fully and report back.

Comment: Dear Fluoxetine:
I feel stupid asking this but the:
#navbar ul ul li {style to apply to li}
You would not use that in the CSS, you would use something like:
.sub2 li a {style to apply to a}
Or even if you where applying text style you could use:
.sub2 {change text style to something in: .sub2 li a}
(I got that from reading the articles you linked to.)

I have to go to work again. 
Thanks again for the answers.

Comment: What kills me about sites like this is I have no idea how to indicate this is the correct answer. I looked around and I find "the person who asked the question can mark an answer as "accepted", but nowhere can I find out HOW to mark a question as accepted!  If you can tell me I will mark your answer as accepted. Cheers, TheWelshman.

Comment: Not sure if that little check mark was there for me to turn green before. Feeling rather sheepish (Being Welsh this is not unusual).

Answer (score 0):

```
#navnar ul 
{/*some style*/} Folder
#navbar ul ul
{/*some style*/} sub-folder

#navbar ul li:hover
{/*some style*/}
#navbar ul ul li:hover
{/*some style*/}
```

I think this is what you're after.

check out this tutorial for more info- [css3-animated-dropdown-menu](http://www.red-team-design.com/css3-animated-dropdown-menu)

Comment: I based my navigation on the above tutorial, you can see how I abused it here: http://dayspring.dioswfl.org/

Comment: I have not forgotten about you but I am new and I need to work out how to inspect the elements in your code! I put the N in newbi. Back to youtube for me.

Comment: Try this it may save you some time sorting through the code. http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/wBa2H/1/

Comment: apaul34208. I like your website, it looks good you have some skill. But what I really need is the code to the "sticky", "stickyX", "drew", "drew-wrap" and "drew-trigger" to understand how you have set the CSS code to achieve the drop down menu. I hate how this closes when you press enter. And thanks for your help.

Comment: The jsFiddle above has all the code that I used. The "sticky" divs are only used to add the fixed position, not really necessary for the drop down menu. If you're really struggling check out the tutorial. It will take you through the basic drop down menu step by step. Note I had to change "menu" to "drew" in my set up because my CMS has a lot of bloated external style sheets, finding an ID that hadn't been used required some creativity.

Comment: Well I have worked out how to check the style and I am no better off. I do not see how you applied the style to the different parts of the drop down menu. I may have all the bones, but I can not put them back together again. 

I am assuming that the "accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" code holds the info I am looking for. I inspected the CSS on that and I do not understand how that code can configure your second level of dropdown boxes. I think I am looking in the wrong place. 
But I did learn how to use Firefox inspect elements and class abilities, so not all lost.
 Cheers.

Comment: The accordion is just used for the map tab in the upper right corner, its not a part of the basic drop down menu.